# Get text bounds of space

Tags: android

How to measure bounds of space in android?

I mean, the following:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();    
paint.getTextBounds(String.valueOf(' '), 0, 1, bounds);
return bounds.width();
```

returns 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to use `paint.measureText(String.valueOf(' '))` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using " (double quotes)

```
paint.getTextBounds(" ", 0, 1, bounds);
```

Comment: this return zero